# Is it possible to use ‘ten from one’ instead of ‘one to ten’?

Tags: grammatical-number

There are one to ten people in the park.

Can I express it as ‘there are ten from one person in the park.’

There are many similar expressions such as ‘more than one,’ ‘less than one,’ ‘one in ten’ and ‘one out of ten.’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "ten from one person in the park" doesn't make any sense.  You could say "There are from one to ten people in the park", but you can't express it "in reverse".

Comment: What about just ‘there is from one person in the park’?

Comment: Like ‘over three people’

Comment: or like ‘up to three people’

Comment: "There are between one and ten people in the park." "There is more than one person..."